# Как работать в C без исключений?

Tags: c, исключения

Я уже знаю, что исключений в языке C не существует.
Но как быть в случае, если функция должна остановить своё выполнение в определённом случае?

```
float quadratic_root(float args[], char sign) {
    float discriminant = pow(args[1], 2) - 4 * args[0] * args[2];
    if (discriminant < 0) {
        exit(1);
    } else {
        float discriminant_root = sqrt(discriminant);
        float root = 
            (sign == '+') ? (-args[1] + discriminant_root) / (2 * args[0]) :
            (-args[1] - discriminant_root) / (2 * args[0]);
        return root;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    float args[3];
    printf("1st arg: "); scanf("%f", &args[0]);
    printf("2nd arg: "); scanf("%f", &args[1]);
    printf("3rd arg: "); scanf("%f", &args[2]);
    printf("\nArgs: %.2f, %.2f, %.2f\n\n", args[0], args[1], args[2]); 
    float root1 = quadratic_root(args, '+');
    float root2 = quadratic_root(args, '-');
    printf("x1: %.4f; x2: %.4f", root1, root2);
    return 0;
}
```

В данном примере - программа, вычисляющая корни квадратного уравнения. Но ведь если дискриминант отрицателен - то корней у квадратного уравнения нет. Что делать, если функция `quadratic_root` должна вернуть значение типа float, а дискриминант отрицателен? Я решил сделать выход из программы. А если мне нужно продолжить выполнение программы в функции `main`? Что делать?

Comment: `break` вам в помощь. или например `return ;`

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержимому. Тут вопрос про обработку ошибок в С.

Comment: 1. Вы можете сами создать механизм типа исключений на основе функций `setjmp()/longjmp()`. 2. Вы можете вернуть из функции что-то типа `inf` или `NaN`, а при выходе из функций проверять результат через `isnan()/isinf()` (но для этого,вроде бы, надо C99). 3. Но правильнее, изменить дизайн функции, как и ответил @Andrej Levkovitch

Comment: Если дискриминант отрицательный, то корнями будут два комплексных числа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таких случаях, конечно, функция не должна зевершать программу - это не приемлимо. Исключения (в с++) это способ выйти из функции возвратив ошибку, которая не предусмотрена возвращаемым значением функции. В вашем случае, например, вы не можете вернуть какое-либо число, так как нельзя потом понять: это результат операции, или ошибка. Так что в данном случае у вас нет другого выбора, как поменять возвращаемое значение. Возвращаемое значение должно возвращать статус: успешно выполнен или нет. А как получить результат? Нужно просто передать указатель на переменную, в которую он и будет записан. Это вполне стандартный подход, который реализован повсеместно (например в posix api).

Comment: *В вашем случае, например, вы не можете вернуть какое-либо число* - вот как раз в **данном** случае, функция вполне может вернуть некое число, сигнализирующще об ошибке. Например: если решения уравнения существуют -  число таких решений (0, 1 или 2) и -1 при отсутствии решений. То, что TS написал в своём коде *return root;* - безусловная **ошибка**!